# How does Django update urls when you add a model to an app?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

If I have an app (blog) and I create a posts model and then add a schedule model how are the urls for schedule created?

Are they imported with the blog.urls like the posts in 3 line below?

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('app.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

Then how would django reference the schedule model views? Is it `path('schedule/,views.scheduleDetail.as_view(),name='sidebar.html')` in the myblog.urls?

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but the `path('',include('app.urls'))` will add all urls in `app.urls`

Comment: I think my confusion is more around how to include a view across multiple templates but I'm getting bogged down with the urls. I did discover that creating a template page for schedule will show my view on the schedule template using the /schedule/ url. So my question here has been answered. Thanks!